# Ruby on Rails two separate polymorphic associations between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now, I found some other stack questions that we're similar but there solutions didn't help. I'm trying to create two seperate polymorphic associations between two tables. I have a users table, a business table and a messages table. I wan't the user to be able to message each other with a one on one conversation.

This is my messages schema:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
       t.references :receiver, polymorphic: true, index: true
       t.text :message
       t.boolean :status, default: false
       t.references :sender, polymorphic: true, index: true
       t.timestamps
     end
  end
end
```

Messages Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sender, polymorphic: true
   belongs_to :receiver, polymorphic: true

   scope :unread, lambda {|| where("status = false")}

end
```

Users Model

```
    has_many :messages, as: :sender
    has_many :messages_out, as: :receiver, source: :messages
```

Business Model

```
    has_many :messages, as: :sender
    has_many :messages_out, as: :receiver, source: :messages
```

Rails Console

```
2.2.1 :060 > User.first.messages_out
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant User::MessagesOut
```

When I try to access messages as sender it works completely fine and I get the expected output. I tried changing the name of the first relationship to something else but then both of the relationships would fail.

```
User.first.messages
```

I tried several variations of this and none of them seem to be working, if setting up my database or model like this is just ill advised, and this setup can't work please let me know and any other setup would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly say which class the `messages_out` method should be loading:

```
has_many :messages_out, as: :receiver, source: :messages, class_name: "Message"
```

Comment: Yeah I tried something like that before and it still gave me an error.       NameError: uninitialized constant User::MessagesOut

Comment: After adding the above line to both User and Business? Not sure what else could be causing it

Comment: Wow yeah it looks like it worked now, I closed my terminal and reopened it and it started working with the solution you gave me. Really weird I was running reload!. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks! It looks like I don't even need the source tag.